# How to use the green "Attach Debugger" button in Python console using PyCharm

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm, console

I was wondering how to use this green bug button on the left side of Python console. I've been searched official documents but there seems to be no description of this button. Note I am asking the button on the left side, not the button on the right top corner.

I'm using IPython console and found `%debug` magic is not available anymore. I'd like to know what's the usage of that button and how to use `%debug` magic in IPython console.

[image]

Comment: did you read the [doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/running-and-debugging.html) on the debugger?

Comment: @idjaw thanks for your reference but this seems doesn't help me understand the usage of that button.

Comment: It runs the debugger. Hover your mouse over it, it will tell you that. You have to set a breakpoint so the debugger knows where to stop, so you can use the debugging tools and step over/into the code. With that in mind, the doc I linked is exactly what you need to then know how to use it properly. There are several other links in there for debugging to teach you how to use it properly

Comment: @idjaw Many thanks for your explanation. But I am still not able to make it work. My workflow is: (previously I've already had a source code file `a.py` and a debug configuration `a_debug`) set a breakpoint in `a.py` -> click the bug button -> select all source code in a.py and execute them in console. Through the whole process nothing happened. Would you please tell me the right workflow?

Comment: Put a breakpoint in your code, run the debugger, it should stop at that breakpoint. This should all be done within PyCharm. I use this feature regularly. That's pretty much all I have to do.

Comment: @idjaw Sorry for the ambiguous. My configuration works normally if I click the button on the right corner. But the button I am asking about is the button on the left.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found your question while searching for the answer myself; eventually I hit upon this video that shows it in use: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JcOCNgXXhmE

Basically, you have to set a breakpoint in a file you're editing, import the file in the console, click the "Attach Debugger" button and then run code that hits the breakpoint -- at that point, the debugger tool will open and you can step through it.

It's not *exactly* what I was hoping for -- I was hoping to attach the debugger and then step through a statement I'd just typed, as one can with IPython's `%debug <statement>` (which still works, but does not provide the visual niceties).

The best solution I've found for that is to use a scratch file, type the statement I want to step through, then run the debugger with that.

Comment: This answer and the YouTube video were very helpful! The thing I didn't get until watching the video is that you need to "import" the file you're looking to debug into the python console.  In the video the command was `import main.` Once I adapted that step to my situation, everything worked as I hoped!

Comment: you are my hero today!

Comment: This seems to be what I was looking for: unfortunately the video is now private and I can't watch it :(