# debug a function in pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pycharm

I have a validator function as part of a bigger program which is fifty lines long which returns `True` or `False` when you give it a string. For a certain string, it is currently returning False, and I don't which of the many return statements is firing. I can open the Python Console of the interpreter and import the function then give it its argument, but not see on which line it is returning False. Would rather not alter the main program to feed it its argument, would also rather not set breakpoints in the program for this. Is it possible in PyCharm to isolate a function, give it your own custom argument and then step through it line by line?

Am using PyCharm version 2018.2.4

Comment: Yes, pycharm supports running unit tests, whether or not your application does isn't something that can be answered.

Comment: It's okay I found the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672258/pycharm-how-to-use-the-green-attach-debugger-button-in-python-console you set the breakpoint in the file then click the "attach debugger" button in the python console then import the function.. Will delete

Comment: Can somebody comment/explain why there are so many down-votes for this question?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible in PyCharm to isolate a function, give it your own custom argument and then step through it line by line?

No, it's not unless you create another file and write something like tests there

By clicking on left side of each line you can declare a breakpoint on the line like this:
[image]

Then you can go to debug tool window and click on the green play button

[image]

> More about [debuging using PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/debugging-your-first-python-application.html)

Also you can use python's `breakpoint()`

It is added as a built-in function in Python 3.7 but u can import it to your file on Python's 3.7-

Comment: Thanks, the thing is how do you isolate the function and give it your own custom argument? Yes, setting a breakpoint lets you step through a program but the argument I want it to have it does not receive when the program runs in its usual way..