# Enter the debugging mode once calling a function from Pycharm console

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I have a program that includes multiple functions. Let assume that I run the program in the debugging mode and it stops at a breakpoint I have indicated (within the main body of the code). While stopped at the breakpoint, is there any way to call another function in the main body (e.g., `Fun1`) from the Pycharm's console and force it to stop in the breakpoint indicated in `Fun1`?

In fact, is there anyway to call a function from the console in a debugging mode (or any other method to reach the same result)? Please let me know if you need further clarification.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pycharm: How to use the green "Attach Debugger" button in python console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39672258/pycharm-how-to-use-the-green-attach-debugger-button-in-python-console)

Comment: @bad_coder It is a different functionality than what OP is asking for. The OP is asking how to debug a function in the current ongoing debugging session (probably you need to pass in some existing variables from the current debugging session to the function as arguments)

Comment: @omsrisagar the problem was also missing an MRE, just the abstract description isn't enough to understand what's intended.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the **Watch** window in pycharm to call the function.
For example,

```
def main():
    print('Some code')  # Let's say you have the debug point here
    result = func1()

def func1():
    return 1
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! But this is not working for me. Once I run the function using the Watches pan, it does not stop at the breakpoint I have indicated in the function.

Comment: If you want to stop at the breakpoint in Func1 then you can use F9 key which stops at next breakpoint.

Use
F7 - to go inside the function,
F8 - to go on next line,
F9 - to execute the code until the next breakpoint
@mdslt

Comment: I see your point and I am aware of that. Thanks! However, I want to run the function in the debugging mode while I have stopped at the first breakpoint so I can run the function multiple times and find its problem. Note that I have used this feature in MATLAB and it is very useful!